# jquery unable to log input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div id="Background">
    <input id="search-Bar" type="text"> 
    <button id="SearchButton">Search</button>
</div>

var name = $("#search-Bar").val();
$("#SearchButton").on("click", function() {
    console.log(name);
});
```

i am trying to get the value of the input using .val() but when i console log it turns out blank every time, can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: put `var name = $("#search-Bar").val();` inside click

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#SearchButton").on("click", function() {
  var name = $("#search-Bar").val(); //this should be here

  console.log(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Background">
  <input id="search-Bar" type="text">
  <button id="SearchButton"> Search </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` variable is being set **only once** on script load, when it's actually empty and stays at this state.

Declare it inside the functions body to get a new, actual value with every function call.

```js
$("#SearchButton").on("click", function() {
  var name = $("#search-Bar").val();
  console.log(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Background"></div>
<input id="search-Bar" type="text">
<button id="SearchButton"> Search </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value using : `$('#search-Bar').val()`

```js
var name = $("#search-Bar").val();
$("#SearchButton").on("click", function(){
    console.log($('#search-Bar').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Background">
<input id="search-Bar" type="text"> 
<button id="SearchButton"> Search </button>
```